# Why doesn't Boost.Range is_sorted require forward iterators?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, iterator, boost-range

The C++11 algorithms `std::is_sorted` and `std::is_sorted_until` both require `ForwardIterator`s. However, the Boost.Range version `boost::is_sorted` only requires `SinglePassRange`s which corresponds to `InputIterator`s. In particular, it delegates to an an iterator-based implementation like this:

```
template<class Iterator, class Comp>
inline Iterator is_sorted_until (Iterator first, Iterator last, Comp c) {
  if (first == last)
    return last;

  Iterator it = first; ++it;

  for (; it != last; first = it, ++it)
    if (c(*it, *first))
      return it;

  return it;
}
```

Here we see a `*first` iterator dereference that happens after the `++it` iterator increment. This means that `Iterator` should have `ForwardIterator` as its required category. Why? Because the Standard says so in

**24.2.3 Input iterators [input.iterators]/p2** (see table 107 with the line about `++r`)

> post: any copies of the previous value of `r` are no longer required
>   either to be dereferenceable or to be in the domain of `==`.

**Note**: this is not intended to be "a proof by single example", but it seems that any comparison based algorithm (e.g. `adjacent_find`) would necessarily require forward iterators in order to be able to make a comparison between two iterators.

**Question**: why doesn't the Boost.Range version of `is_sorted` require the stronger concept of `ForwardRange` (and `ForwardIterator` for its low-level routines) that is required by `std::is_sorted`? Is it a bug in Boost.Range?

Comment: Indeed this seems suspicious.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I wonder though if one could make it work for input iterators by caching the last value that has been read?

Comment: It would then impose a requirement on said value: it would have to be copyable.

Comment: Hmmm doesn't a SinglePassRange correspond to a SinglePassIterator rather than an InputIterator? See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/new-iter-concepts.html#single-pass-iterators-lib-single-pass-iterators

Comment: @dyp [Earlier in that document](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/new-iter-concepts.html#design), InputIterator is said to be a readable SinglePassIterator. And just below your quoted passage, there is the table for ForwardIterator which has "r == s and r is dereferenceable implies ++r == ++s." Without this, the previous value is no longer dereferenceable or comparable if copies of the iterator are incremented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the iterator versions in boost.algorithm correctly require `ForwardIterators`. And believe it or not, [**there are also range-based versions in boost.algorithm.**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/the_boost_algorithm_library/CXX11/is_sorted.html) Code duplication at its best. The documentation is lagging behind the source according to [Ticket #9367](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9367), [Changeset #86741](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/changeset/86741) corrects the rest of the documentation to state that all flavors of the sort-checking algorithms require `ForwardIterators`.

I would prefer the implementations in `<boost/algorithm/cxx11/is_sorted.hpp>` over those in `<boost/range/algorithm_ext/is_sorted.hpp>` which seem to be bit-rotting since 2010.

EDIT: Digging around, it appears that the Boost.Range implementations *did* require `ForwardIterator`, but [this commit broke them in 2010?!?](https://github.com/boostorg/range/commit/367582d0f414ba7098081c69b8b86428905f6f2f).

Comment: +1 and accepted. thanks for digging up all that dirt on Boost. It's a mess to say it nicely.